# Can I have RequiredFieldValidator to check for more than one ControlToValidate?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, requiredfieldvalidator

I am having 3 `TextBox`es in a row and then a Next button.

On clicking Next button, the control would go to the next page only if ALL of the 3 `TextBox`es contain some user-entered text.

Is there any option by which I can check whether all of the `TextBox`es contain some text by using `RequiredFieldValidator` (rather than going for different RequiredFieldValidator for each `ControlToValidate`)?

I am currently having following code:

```
          <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDOB" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Size="Medium"
                    ForeColor="Black" Text="Date of Birth"></asp:Label>
            </td>
              <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server" Width="45px"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" Width="45px"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtC" runat="server" Width="45px"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtA"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter Text">
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtB"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter Text">
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtC"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter Text">
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

So, instead of having 3 different `RequiredFieldValidator`s, I want to use only a single `RequiredFieldValidator` which checks if all the 3 TextBoxes contain some text. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) and combine with either client side javascript or server side c#/vb.net code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate more than one control using `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the `RequiredFieldValidator` with more than one control ,
 but i prefer to use the HTML5 required attribute instead of ASP.NET Validation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" required="required" />
```

Comment: Whilst you can (and should for accessibility reasons) use the HTML5 required attribute in addition to other validation methods, this should be as well as - rather than in place of - Server Side validation. Whilst it would be perfectly valid to use a custom validator with no client side script- relying on the required attribute to provide dynamic notification - the required attribute cannot be relied on in isolation. The attribute is not supported in all browsers, can be tampered with by a malicious user, and won't protect you if data is posted directly to the page.